# Which button on my UIAlertView did the user press?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uialertview, uialertviewdelegate

I've created a `UIAlertView` and now I want to check which button the user presses.

My code is:

```
- (IBAction)button1 {
    {
        UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
        [alert1 setTitle:@"Hello"];
        [alert1 setMessage:@"Do you like smoking?"];
        [alert1 addButtonWithTitle:@"Yes"];
        [alert1 addButtonWithTitle:@"No"];
        [alert1 show];
    }
}
```

How can I check it with if-else statement?

Answer (score 4):

You must set the delegate of your `UIAlertView` to the class that will handle the callbacks from the `UIAlertView` itself

E.g.

```
[alert1 setDelegate:self];
```

Where `self` is your current `UIViewController` that implements the protocol `<UIAlertViewDelegate>`.

When the user taps a button, the `UIAlertView` will call back to whatever object you set as the delegate, in my example we are using the `UIViewController` that created the `UIAlertView`. Once we get the callback, we can check which button index has been tapped and act accordingly.  This is a basic delegation pattern that is used throughout iOS development, especially UIKit.

**Example**

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController() <UIAlertViewDelegate>
@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (IBAction)button1 {
    {
        UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
        [alert1 setTitle:@"Hello"];
        [alert1 setMessage:@"Do you like smoking?"];
        [alert1 addButtonWithTitle:@"Yes"];
        [alert1 addButtonWithTitle:@"No"];
        [alert1 setDelegate:self];
        [alert1 show];
    }
}

#pragma mark - UIAlertViewDelegate

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
   // Handle interaction
       switch (buttonIndex)
       {
           case 0:
             NSLog(@"Yes was pressed");
             break;
           case 1:
             NSLog(@"No was pressed");
             break;
       }
}

@end
```

It is very important you specify in the header file, or class interface extension that your class implements the `<UIAlertViewDelegate>`.

I recommend you see the [UIAlertViewDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html) for more information, and you can follow this approach for many other UIKit components.

Comment: I know this is a year old, but even some of the code I find that is that old doesn't work. iOS 8.1 & Xcode 6.1 tested & works! :) Although I personally had to add in two more if's, still applied it, and runs amazingly! Thanks!!!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Although you should probably consider moving to `UIAlertController` now.

Comment: I saw that yesterday while rummaging through the Apple Docs. Will this still work with it?

Comment: UIAlertController works slightly differently, as it is an entire UIViewController that you present modally. Definitely worth reading up on, but it is straight forward to transition.

Answer (score 2):

Implement `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol in your view controller, set it as a delegate to the `UIAlertView`, and wait for the `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` event, like this:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
      clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
@end

@implementation MyViewController

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
    clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSLog(@"Button %d clicked...", (int)buttonIndex);
}

@end
```

Change the code that displays the alert view as follows:

```
UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
[alert1 setTitle:@"Hello"];
[alert1 setMessage:@"Do you like smoking?"];
[alert1 addButtonWithTitle:@"Yes"];
[alert1 addButtonWithTitle:@"No"];
alert1.delegate = self; // <<== Add this line
[alert1 show];
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to the answer by Jeff, I think that you have to enable the other button in order to place your logic when the button is clicked.

In order to creating the button with your code:

```
- (IBAction)button1 
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello"
                                                        message:@"Do you like smoking?"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"No", nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

But before knowing which button is clicked, you have to enable the first other button, by calling this delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    return YES;
}
```

This will enable the NO button that you have created. Then, you will be able to do some logic with the clickedButtonAtIndex method, which I suppose you will be doing.

Implement the UIAlertView delegate method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        // i love smoking!
    } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        // i hate smoking!
    }
}
```

Be sure to declare the UIAlertViewDelegate in your header class.

Make sure that the alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton: method returns YES, if not you will not be able to put in your logic for when the button is pressed.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks your code totally work ONLY THIS ONE WORKING AND ONLY THIS CODE NOT RATE :)

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is make the class that presents your alert view conform to the `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol and implement the method `–alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:`. That way you'll know what button was clicked.

Hope this helps!